# Simulate click of javascript Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i simulate a click of the button below? I tried using the javascript 
    `$("#Save").click()` but it didnt work. Does this have to do with it not working because there is no id but name?

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="OnSubmit(this.form);">
```

What javascript command in my browser would i use to simulate the click of Save following something like i tried to use?

Much help appreciated! Im new to this

Comment: You need the `id="Save"` because the `#` sign in your JQuery selector means it is selecting the ID following it (Save in your case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears your using jQuery with an id selector (`#` denotes an id), however the element doesn't have an id.  Since the element does have a name attribute, an attribute selector can be used by jQuery.  An appropriate selector would be:

```
$('input[name="Save"]').click(); //Assuming no other elements have name=Save
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pJD3R/

You could also change the markup to work with your existing selector by adding an `id` attribute:

```
<input id="Save" class="button" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="OnSubmit(this.form);">
```

Comment: Supousing he has not another input with name 'Save'

Comment: @Ander2 Agreed another element with the name `Save` would cause issues.

Answer (score 4):

`$("#Save").click()` mean you target an element with the id `save` but you don't have any id on your input.

```
<input class="button" id="save" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="OnSubmit(this.form);">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=Save]').click(function(){
    alert('Do Something');
});
```

Comment: I thought the value required quotes, but I just tested a fiddle that worked without the quotes. Interesting. Documentation states:  `value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.`  I didn't know that.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes in this case works, but is better use always quotes, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: So something like `my name` would fail due to the space?